# Strapi.io- How to throw alert message to contentmanager ui from beforeupdate/beforesave function in controller

Tags: strapi

Want to add a Validation Logic in Before Save / Before Create Values in Controller.

Want to throw the Error to the Admin Panel User. Hence they can correct the same value and resubmit the Form

BeforeSave : I am able to add the logic. But i dont know how to throw the Error Message as a Alert to the Content Manager panel . (This form has Errors)

Code snippets
Tried this ...but not working

errors.push({ id: 'content-manager.error.validation.json' });
strapi.notification.error('settings-manager.strapi.notification.error')

Comment: You are trying to add something in the backend or in the frontend of Strapi?

Comment: I need to throw the validation specific error/alert message in Front End of Strapi. (ContentType - > Save)

Answer (score 4):

In case you're still struggling with this: using model lifecycle callbacks, throwing an `Error` should suffice.

For example, in `./api/user/models/User.js`, you can do this:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  beforeSave: async (model, attrs, options) => {
    if (someValidationFails(model)) {
      throw new Error('Custom error message.');
    }
  },
};
```

Other than the error message showing up in green for some reason, this should work.

Comment: With Strapi v3.3.x throwing a simple Error was not enough for me, because it prevents the saving of the object, but the error message is not shown. I have to throw strapi errors like this: `throw strapi.errors.badRequest('This will appear in a pop-up')`

Comment: @dappiu your solution works, do you know where the docs are for this? It would be good to know what other error types are available

Comment: @mrmadhat it's very unfortunate that no official documentation about this exists. I had to look through the strapi and strapi-admin repositories' code to get to know this, and for what I remember no other error type exists. I think I have read about this also on some issue in the strapi GitHub repository.

Comment: With Strapi v4.x, if you want to see the error as a Popup in the administration frontend an ApplicationError must be thrown (from @strapi/utils errors).

Answer (score 0):

Im using strapi v3.9, you can use:

```
const utils = require('@strapi/utils');
const { ApplicationError } = utils.errors;

throw new ApplicationError('Something went wrong');
```

More details in docs: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/error-handling